# Applying texture to a specific colour

Tags: texturing

I just started using Blender.
I have a png file used as texture, and I would like to apply a glossy finish only to one colour of the image. Is there any way I can do it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you need to create a b&w mask and use it as a factor in the Glossy socket (or as a factor in a Mix Shader between the Diffuse and the Glossy)

Comment: I think [this shader setup](https://i.imgur.com/TRk6okL.png) should work. Color2 on the Difference node is the color you want to be glossy.